does NitroJS (server of NuxtJS) have a Dependency Injection like NestJS at the constructor level from the app singleton or perRequest?
does NitroJS (server of NuxtJS) support dependency injection as the following ?
call any dependency from the class constructor "dependency injection: inversion of control (IoC)" and let the framework get/initialize it from the singleton reflection like laravel and nestJS as below examples
Laravel example:
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
 
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected UserRepository $users,
    ) {}
}

nestJS example:
import { Controller, Get, Bind, Dependencies } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private catsService: CatsService){}

  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }
}

